# std_logic_signed is used but not declared

Tags: vhdl

I am new to VHDL. I am trying to use a std_logic_signed signal but I keep getting the error "std_logic_signed is used but not declared". As far as I can tell I have used the right libraries but googeling the error resulted in a lot of conflicting answers.

Here is my sample program:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity bird is

end entity bird;

architecture arch of bird is

--Declare signals
signal speed : std_logic_signed (7 downto 0);

begin

end architecture arch;
```

What is causing the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Because the type name is SIGNED:

```
grep -i signed std_logic_arith.vhdl 
std_logic_arith.vhdl:    type SIGNED is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;
...
```

There isn't a type declared named std_logic_signed.

Instead of declaring speed with a type mark of `std_logic_signed` use `signed`:

```
--Declare signals
signal speed : signed (7 downto 0);
```